# Mapped data containing buttons throwing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'onSubmit' of undefined"

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs

I am writing a full stack application that displays questions from my sql server and displays on the front end. 
Within each of these questions there is an accept and decline button. I simply want my accept to send a response to my db and decline to send a response to my db (both different of course).

However when creating the question and creating a on submit that binds to on handle submit it throws an error(listed below).

How would I make two separate handle submits for each answer in which the data could then be sent to another table but using the ID on the mapped question so it can be used as a foreign key.

Is this because it is mapped data?

Code in question

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./customers.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class DisplayUsers extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { questions: [], QuestionsAnswer: [], QuestionsSeverity: [] };
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      questions: this.getItems()
    });
  }

  getItems() {
    fetch("/user-questions")
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        console.log(results.recordset);
        this.setState({ questions: results.recordset });
      });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      QuestionsAnswer: this.state.QuestionsAnswer,
      QuestionsSeverity: this.state.QuestionsSeverity
    };

    fetch("/Question-Response", {
      method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log("Success:", data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.questions);
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.questions &&
          this.state.questions.map(function(question, index) {
            return (
              <div className="jumbotron">
                <li> Question ID: {question.QuestionId}</li>
                <li> Question:{question.Question}</li>
                <li>
                  <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Accepted</button> 
                  <button>Declined</button>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <textarea
                    onChange={e =>
                      this.setState({ QuestionsAnswer: e.target.value })
                    }
                    rows="4"
                    cols="160"
                    id="TITLE"
                  ></textarea>
                </li>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default DisplayUsers;
```

error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'onSubmit' of undefined
    at DisplayQuestions.js:62
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at DisplayUsers.render (DisplayQuestions.js:54)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18470)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18423)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20186)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:385)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:440)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25780)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24695)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24671)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24270)
    at react-dom.development.js:12199
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:697)
    at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:12149)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:12194)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:12182)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23709)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:13994)
    at DisplayUsers.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:325)
    at DisplayQuestions.js:23
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope issue.

In the render function add `var self = this;` just above `console.log(this.state.questions);` and then use `self.onSubmit`.

You are within the scope of `this.state.questions.map`'s callback function so `this` does not refer to the component.

```
  render() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(this.state.questions);
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.questions &&
          this.state.questions.map(function mapFn(question, index) {
              ...
                  // this === scope of mapFn ↑ which is undefined
                  // self === scope of render function
                  <button onClick={self.onSubmit}>Accepted</button> 
      ....
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

**Edit**

Another way and probably **better** is to pass the scope to the map function

```
this.state.questions.map(function(question, index) {
    // this === scope of render function
}, this)
```